# Search by Postal Code on Bing Map API Java

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, bing-api

Is there a way to search addresses by their postal code on Bing Map but just by their postal code because now if I search for example by the postal code ( 520 let's say, in Germany ) I retrieves a list of all addresses with 520  as a street number instead of showing all postal codes starting with 520.

Comment: in Java or Javascript?

Comment: Doesn't seem like there are any options other than just passing a query to the search and hoping for the best... Maybe you can filter the returned results client-side on postal code?

Comment: In Javascript. It seems that you can achieve this using this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/locations/find-a-location-by-address , but I was hoping there is a better solution

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.